# Not to make bootstrap panel header components wrap

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I have a bootstrap panel (inside a col-xs-6) and the panel header has two sections.

1. long text inside caret <>
2. buttons at the end

I want to make sure that caret is always visible and all are in one single line (no warp)
the text inside has " text-overflow: ellipsis" so that it the text doesn't fit, it can do ...

Fiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: I think your fiddle is missing its content.  Did you click save?  Also, btw, you can include snippets of runnable code directly on stackoverfow now.  You can read more about it here: https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
<div style='white-space:nowrap;'> your long text </div>
```

Description of 'nowrap' from [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp):

> Sequences of whitespace will collapse into a single whitespace. Text will never wrap to the next line. The text continues on the same line until a tag is encountered