# Bootstrap panel header, how to prevent text wrapping

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a Bootstrap panel which has header text and action buttons on the right. I always want the buttons to be in the top-right of the panel header.

When the text gets longer than one line, it wraps and displaces the buttons. How can I prevent this?

https://jsfiddle.net/PHPMickB/gsc9zt8k/

I saw a similar question but this did not work:

[Not to make bootstrap panel header components wrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44145470/not-to-make-bootstrap-panel-header-components-wrap)

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-8 col-lg-offset-2">
            <h1>Title</h1>
            <div class="panel-group">


                <div class="panel panel-warning">
                    <div class="panel-heading skinny">
                        <h4 class="panel-title pull-left">
                <span data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse45">Tenetur tenetur temporibus tempora ipsam. Tenetur tenetur temporibus tempora ipsam.Tenetur tenetur temporibus tempora ipsam.
                </span>
                        </h4>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <div class="input-group-btn text-right">
                                <button onclick="btnSnoozeClick('1onDgk')" class="btn btn-warning"><i
                                            class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></i></button>
                                <button onclick="btnCompleteClick('1onDgk')" class="btn btn-warning"><i
                                            class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i></button>
                                <button onclick="btnDeleteClick('1onDgk')" class="btn btn-warning"><i
                                            class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i></button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapse45" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            Sed vel natus ut voluptas et.
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="panel panel-success">
                    <div class="panel-heading skinny">
                        <h4 class="panel-title pull-left">
                <span data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse45">Tenetur tenetur te
                </span>
                        </h4>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <div class="input-group-btn text-right">
                                <button onclick="btnSnoozeClick('1onDgk')" class="btn btn-success"><i
                                            class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></i></button>
                                <button onclick="btnCompleteClick('1onDgk')" class="btn btn-success"><i
                                            class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i></button>
                                <button onclick="btnDeleteClick('1onDgk')" class="btn btn-success"><i
                                            class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i></button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapse45" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            Sed vel natus ut voluptas et.
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>



            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks,

Mick

Comment: something like this https://jsfiddle.net/gsc9zt8k/2/

Comment: Yes, exactly like that! What was I doing wrong? Add that as an answer, so I can accept.

Comment: He put the text and the button group into separate columns (`col-md-8` on the left, `col-md-4` on the right) which is then all wrapped in a row to organize them side-by-side.

Comment: So just basic Bootstrap columns. Simple.

Answer (score 0):

Apply a max-width to the title. If the buttons are always a fixed size and number, calc sould work. Please note that I also added the row class to the panel heading element to clear the floats (to grow the element with the text). A better solution would be to simply add a clear class rather than adding row and remove the margins, however it works perfectly this way.

```
.panel-title {
  max-width:calc(100% - 120px);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gsc9zt8k/5/